# Precise method to set alarms in Android 6.0

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-6.0-marshmallow

[`setAlarmclock()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setAlarmClock(android.app.AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo,%20android.app.PendingIntent)), [`setAndAllowWhileIdle()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) and 
[`setExactandAllowWhileIdle()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) are the methods described in the documentation for an alarm to be able to cut through Doze and App Standby modes.

However, there have been reports by multiple nexus users who use [Google Clock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.deskclock) that the alarm did not work on their devices (Google Clock uses [`setAlarmclock()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setAlarmClock(android.app.AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) with [`setExact()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) method).

[`setAndAllowWhileIdle()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) has been [reported](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2233) to be not affecting the Doze mode, whereas [`setExactandAllowWhileIdle()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) is said to be [working](https://twitter.com/commonsguy/status/651504486226259968), but only with a gap of 15 minutes.

I need to be able to schedule alarms with intervals of at least 5 minutes. What should be the right approach here?

Comment: Send GCM messages from a server every five minutes to your app on the device.

Comment: Does this come under the acceptable use cases for a non-messaging app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently [found](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2930&thanks=2930&ts=1439405162) that an alarm set with [`setAlarmClock`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setAlarmClock(android.app.AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) keeps the device from entering IDLE mode within 2 hours of the alarm setting off. It seems like using [`setAlarmClock`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setAlarmClock(android.app.AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) with [`setExactAndAllowWhileIdle`](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) is the best approach to go for on `Marshmallow`.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no solution to your problem of firing alarm every 5 minutes. You won't be able to cut through the doze mode with your requirement. You must think of a way to increase the alarm time period. Also using GCM messages for a non-messaging app may result in a violation according to ["Acceptable Use Cases for Whitelisting"](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#whitelisting-cases).

Also you can't set a repeating alarm while the device is in doze mode. You must set the alarm using the APIs above and re-register them again when they go off!

Comment: But isn't this possible if the device doesn't go in the doze mode, like when I schedule the alarm with AlarmClock.setAlarmClock()?

Comment: If not in doze mode, then it should work. Although, I must admit I haven't tried these APIs in marshmallow. But I guess with your kind of requirement, you won't let the device drift into doze mode as you will be waking it up every 5 mins. Did you try the api with 5 minutes repeated interval on marshmallow?

Comment: I tried setting alarm with AlarmClock.setAlarmClock() and it does keep the device out of doze mode 60 minutes before it is triggered.

Comment: I am not aware of your complete requirement. Interval of repetition of 5 minutes should not be a worry as doze mode will never set in. What should worry you is your initial trigger getting ignored cos of the doze mode. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But in the previews of Marshmallow it was reported setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() was not working as intended. But it does work in the later releases. I asked this question at that time to clear the doubt.

Comment: Oh ok. I guess that problem was eliminated in the final release because of late I haven't heard these APIs creating any trouble. Hope things worked out well with your app.

Comment: Yes, on all the devices I've tested, things seem to work well, but some nexus users using google clock have reported that their alarm did not go off, as I mentioned in the question. I also wanted to clear this confusion.

Comment: Oh! In that case you must check it on the Moto G series. Moto G, 2nd gen and 3rd gen already received Marshmallow updates. Best Of Luck!

Comment: Yes, I intend to do the same. Thank you!